# Remove Dropdownlist with no values

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have little problem.
I'm dynamically populating grid view from the values from the database.
I'm trying to remove DropDownList's that don't have any values.

I have this code for now:

```
if (ddlMyDropDown.Items.Count == 0)
 {
     ddlMyDropDown = false;
 }
else
 {
     ddlMyDropDown = true;
 }
```

This code works fine but it has one problem. 
It doesn't remove DDL's that have index 0. 
It remove's only index from 1 to higher value, and emtpy DDL's with index of 0 are shown on the screen.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do it with css. Like:  ddlMyDropDown.Attributes[&quot;style&quot;] = &quot;display:none&quot;

if you dont want to render code like:
ddlMyDropDown.Visible = false

Comment: Thanks for help but I need done through c#